# Display multiple variables?

Tags: c#

I'm initializing the same variable in two places.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Stat definitions

    // Player
    int PlayerHP = 10;
    int PlayerAtt = 6;
    int PlayerDef = 4;
    // Enemy
    int EnemyHP = 10;
    int EnemyAtt = 5;
    int EnemyDef = 5;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StatList();
    }

    public void Combat()
    {
        if (PlayerAtt > EnemyDef)
        {
            EnemyHP--;
            CombatLog.Text = "Enemy HP: " + EnemyHP;
        }
    }

    public void Death()
    {
        if (EnemyHP < 0)
        {
            EnemyHP = 0;
        }

        if (EnemyHP == 0)
        {
            CombatLog.Text = "The Enemy has Fallen!";
        }

        if (PlayerHP < 0)
        {
            PlayerHP = 0;
        }

        if (PlayerHP == 0)
        {
            CombatLog.Text = "The Player has Fallen!";
        }
    }

    public void StatList()
    {
        PlayerStats.Lines = new string[] { "Health: " + PlayerHP, "Attack: " + PlayerAtt, "Defence: " + PlayerDef, };
        EnemyStats.Lines = new string[] { "Health: " + EnemyHP, "Attack: " + EnemyAtt, "Defence: " + EnemyDef, };
    }

    private void Attack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Combat();
        Death();
    }
}
```

}

Anyways, when the updated "EnemyHP" is written in the "CombatLog" the EnemyHP under EnemyStats does not update for the new value and instead stays the same as the original assignment.

I was thinking I could use a loop to constantly check what it comes out to be in the CombatLog and update on the spot but I still need to think of how to write that out.

What does the great Stackoverflow think?

Comment: your question is unclear. what are you trying to achieve? do you want to update `EnemyStats.Lines` when EnemyHP decreased?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to achieve, mind telling me how my question seems unclear?

Comment: You need to recall the StatList method every time your Combat method is called

Comment: How did you declare EnemyHP? is it a static variable?  and did you call StatList() after changing the EnemyHP?

Comment: Where is `EnemyHP` declared and initialized? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: All now have a full view of how the variables are declared and initialized as well as every other detail.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you handle your view, and how your values are updated to the view. I'm assuming you are using WPF ?
You should get informations on the INotifyPropertyChanged interface here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This interface helps you communicating with your view, telling it to refresh the value when it changed.

A smart way to handle your views is to use the MVVM pattern. You can find a great tutorial here :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/03/13/understanding_2d00_the_2d00_basics_2d00_of_2d00_mvvm_2d00_design_2d00_pattern.aspx

Good luck !

Comment: Windows Forms Application is what I'm using I'll checkout your examples though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get EnemyStats updated you need to invoke StatList after Combat.
Note, that each time you invoke EnemyStats you create new string array. It's very wasteful and not effective

Comment: Would would be effective?

Answer (score 0):

Recalling the StatList on every update did resolve the issue.

As this is based in Windows Form Application I have a button that calls all of what is happening here.

My attack button simply needed to call `Statlist();` like so:

```
private void Attack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Combat();
        Death();
        StatList();
    }
```